# Conditional Formatting - Highlight only if first numbers are duplicates

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting, countif

ich have found the CountIF formula. But i can't highlight cells if everything is the same except the last digit.
For example here should be the cells with GA22515089-X highlighted

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use COUNTIF with the constart part of your strings and combined with wildcards. So count how many rows **starts with** same string. IF the count is greater than 1, it's a duplicate:

[image]

Formula:

```
=COUNTIF($A$1:$A$16,LEFT(A1,SEARCH("-",A1))&"*")>1
```